# Calling Console.WriteLine before allocating the console

Tags: c#, console, console.writeline

I've recently encountered the following problem with my application: it didn't show any console output, though the console had been allocated by using `AllocConsole`. I managed to figure out soon that it was caused by an attempt (hidden deeply in code) to write to the console before the `AllocConsole` was called. So it looked like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Foo"); // no console allocated yet
AllocConsole();           // console window appears
Console.WriteLine("Bar"); // expecting "Bar" in the console, but the console is blank
```

So my question is: why does this happen? I don't see any exceptions (though I suppose they are there).

Comment: Now that why it happened has been explained, I hope someone will explain what to do about it. Isn't that any third-party library is use can write to Console and screw up things for all others? Is the right solution only to decide early and `AllocConsole` before doing anything else?

Comment: @Hemal I used an approach, described by Rick - calling `Console.OpenStandartOutput()` after `AllocConsole`. This way I can be sure that at least all output written after `AllocConsole` will be shown.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first time you use `Console.WriteLine`, the `Console` class creates a `TextWriter` and associates it with the `Console.Out` property.  The way it does this is to use Win32 to open the low-level file handle associated with the **standard output** file handle.  If the standard output handle is invalid, `Console.Out` is set to [`TextWriter.Null`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.null.aspx), which discards all output.

The Win32 `AllocConsole` function, creates and sets the standard output handle so after calling it the standard output handle is either different or now valid.  In either case, `Console.Out` has already been set either to use the *old* standard output or to discard all output.

To force a re-open of `Console.Out` after calling `AllocConsole`, you can use this method:

- [`Console.OpenStandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16f09842.aspx)

Comment: Wow. In case anyone else see this, it seems that this can happen as if it's a race condition-- Alloc, then write to Console & get nothing.  Also, I had to write Console.SetOut(new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput()); Calling Console.OpenStandardOutput() alone didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the static constructor of the `Console` class sets up the output stream the first time you call `Console.WriteLine`. Since there's no console attached, and therefore no standard output handle, output gets routed to the bit bucket. And when you call `AllocConsole` later, nothing in the `Console` class is notified that a console now exists. It doesn't have the opportunity to attach `Console.Out` to the newly created standard output handle.

Answer (score 0):

A process can be associated with only one `console`, so the `AllocConsole` `function` fails if the calling process already has a `console`. And the `console` application is already has the `console`. See details in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: My app is compiled as a GUI application, but it uses the console when run using command line parameters.

Comment: How do you know that this is a console application? It may very well be a Windows application with a console. *Edit:* told you.

Comment: Console.WriteLine was writen above the AllocConsole so i thought it was. any way i apologize for this :) GetLastError() might tell you something in this case